# Query SharePoint List Items with Javascript without limit

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

i am querying currently a SharePoint List through JavaScript Object Model to get all the items. How do i have to query a list in JavaScript to havent a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through RowLimit Parameter inside CAML Query.

[How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)